# How get networking working in QEMU VM on macOS XI

Tags: networking, virtual-machine, qemu, macos

I'm trying to run Linux VMs on macOS XI using QEMU which works just fine.
I'd also like to access the internet from the VM and communicate with it via SSH but networking does not work OOTB like it does on Linux. (The VM gets an IP address in a separate subnet, can't ping the internet, nor the host's IP address in the real subnet.)

How can I get that to work?
What are my options?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out only ping/icmp doesn't work. HTTP etc. work just fine OOTB without any special options.

Host-to-vm communication is harder though and probably already answered elsewhere.